# Wordpress: Custom Post type leads to 404 Page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a wordpress site I am managing. We successfully added a custom post type called "Partner." I have created a Partners page to list my partners, and this works correctly. But from that page when I click on the link for a given partner, rather than go to a partner page I get a 404 error. Likewise, if I click on the permalink URL in the Admin for the partner entry, I get the same 404.

I have made sure that I have a single-partner.php page (and that I have a single.php to fall back to) and just in case I also made sure I have a post-partner.php and an archive-partner.php.   Here is the code I have that creates the post type (and an associated taxonomy for Categories)

```
class Xoo_Custom_Post_Type{

    public $postSlug = 'partner';

    public $taxSlug = 'partner_category';
public function __construct(){
    $this->hooks();
}


public function hooks(){
    add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'registerPostType' ) );
    add_shortcode( 'xoo_partners_ui', array( $this, 'shortcode' ) );
    add_shortcode( 'xoo_partners_categories', array( $this, 'short_shortcode' ) );
}

public function registerPostType(){

    $partnerlabels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Partners', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Partner', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Partners' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Partners' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Partner' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Partner:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Partner' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Partner' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Partner' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Partner Name' ),
    );

    $partnerargs = array(
        'labels'            => $partnerlabels,
        'public'            => true,
        'show_ui'           => true, // UI in admin panel
        '_builtin'          => false, // It's a custom post type, not built in!
        '_edit_link'        => 'post.php?post=%d',
        'show_in_menu'      => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'capability_type'   => 'post',
        'hierarchical'      => false,
        'supports'          => array('title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail'),
        'has_archive'       => 'partners'
    );

    register_post_type( $this->postSlug, $partnerargs );


    //Register Category Taxonomy
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Categories', 'taxonomy general name', 'textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Category', 'taxonomy singular name', 'textdomain' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Categories', 'textdomain' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Categories', 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Category', 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Category:', 'textdomain' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Category', 'textdomain' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Category', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Category', 'textdomain' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Category Name', 'textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Categories', 'textdomain' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
    );

    register_taxonomy( $this->taxSlug, array( $this->postSlug ), $args );

}


public function getCategories(){

    $args = array(
        'taxonomy'      => $this->taxSlug,
        'orderby'       => 'name',
        'order'         => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty'    => false,
    );

    return get_categories($args);

}

public function getAllPartners() {
    
    return get_posts( array(
        'post_type'     => $this->postSlug,
        'numberposts'   => -1,
        'tax_query'     => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'  => $this->taxSlug,
                'field'     => 'term_id', 
                
            )
        )
    ) );
}


public function getPartnersByCategory( $category_id ){

    return get_posts( array(
        'post_type'     => $this->postSlug,
        'numberposts'   => -1,
        'tax_query'     => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'  => $this->taxSlug,
                'field'     => 'term_id', 
                'terms'     => $category_id,
            )
        )
    ) );

}



public function short_shortcode() {
    
    $categories = $this->getCategories();
    
    if( empty( $categories ) ){
        return __( '' );
    }
    
    ob_start();
    
    foreach ( $categories as $index => $category ) {
        echo '<li><a id="' . str_ireplace(' ','_',$category->name) . '">' . $category ->name . '</a></li>';
    }
    
    return ob_get_clean();
}

public function shortcode(){

    $categories = $this->getCategories();
    
    if( empty( $categories ) ){
        return __( 'No categories found' );
    }

    ob_start();

    echo '<ul>';

    foreach ( $categories as $index => $category ) {

        echo '<li>';

        esc_html_e( $category->name );

        $partners = $this->getPartnersByCategory( $category->term_id );

        echo '<ul>';

        foreach ( $partners as $partner ) {
            printf( '<li><a href="%1$s">%2$s</a></li>', esc_url( get_permalink( $partner->ID ) ), esc_html( $partner->post_title ) );
        }
        
        echo '</ul>';

        echo '</li>';
        }

        echo '</ul>';

        return ob_get_clean();
    }

}

add_action( 'init', function(){
    new Xoo_Custom_Post_Type();
}, 0 );
```

And likewise, here is the code on my page that is creating the permalinks per post that give me the 404 errors:

```
<?php 
                
                    $args = array(
                        'taxonomy'      => 'partner_category',
                        'orderby'       => 'name',
                        'order'         => 'ASC',
                        'hide_empty'    => false,
                    );

                    $loopa = get_categories($args);
                    if (!empty($loopa)) { 
                        foreach( $loopa as $category) { 
                            $posts = get_posts( array(
                                                        'post_type'     => 'partner',
                                                        'numberposts'   => -1,
                                                        'orderby'       => 'title',
                                                        'order'         => 'ASC',
                                                        'tax_query'     => array(
                                                            array(
                                                                'taxonomy'  => 'partner_category',
                                                                'field'     => 'term_id', 
                                                                'terms'     => $category->term_id,
                                                            )
                                                        )
                                                ) 
                                    );
                            //print_r($posts);
                        ?>
                        <section id="all-trade-paperback" class="all-comics bottom-content-wrap <?php echo str_ireplace(' ','_',$category->name) ?>">
                            <h1 class="upper-82 standard-case blue"><?php echo tCase( $category->name ) ?></h1>
                            
                            <div class="letter-content-wrap float-wrap white series-comics">
                                        <ul class="col-2-layout standard-40-bold upper float-left col-91">
                                            <?php foreach( $posts as $post ) {  ?>
                                                    <li data-title="<?php echo $post->post_title?>">
                                                        <a class="white" href="<?php get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></a>
                                                    </li>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                        </ul>
                            </div>
                        </section>
                        <?php }
                    }
                    
                ?>
```

My hope is that, by sharing my code here, someone better versed in WordPress can point out wherein my idiocy lies, and what I should change to resolve the 404 error. Thanks!

P.S. needless to say, while I have tried to be thorough in my posting, if I left out any relevant details please let me know and I can include them.

Comment: Did you re-save your site's permalink structure? Sometimes this is needed for WP to be able to route requests to your CPTs.

Comment: I did not, but thank you for the suggestion. I will try it out.

Comment: That did it. At least something changed and its no longer going to the 404 page. =)  If you want to post that as an answer I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that when registering new post types you need to re-save your site's permalink structure for WordPress to be able to route requests correctly, so go to **Settings > Permalinks**, click on **Save Changes**, and that should do the trick :)

Comment: Apparently WordPress caches the permalink structure which is why sometimes when you register a new one you may get a 404 error when visiting the new URLs: WordPress doesn't know about them yet (or something along those lines.) When you click on Save Changes, as far as I understand at least, you force WordPress to regenerate its permalink structure cache (hence why this "trick" works.)

Comment: Thanks again! This was very helpful

Comment: Don't mention it. Have a nice day!